# How to use fetch only when data has not already been loaded

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a javascript function which triggers when a `button` is clicked. The function takes a `data-attribute` from the `button` element, and uses this as a key to find a value from a JSON dataset.

If the JSON data has already been downloaded from the first button click, I don't want to download the dataset again as there is no reason to do so.

I have tried to do this by declaring an empty array. I then find the length of the array, if the length is 0, I get the JSON data and push it to the array. If the array length is more than 0, I know that I can use this data.

I'm not sure why, but every-time I run the function, the data is redownloaded, regardless of the conditional statement.

Here is my code

```js
let arr = [[0,"Bulbasaur"],[1,"Ivysaur"],[2,"Venusaur"],[3,"Charmander"],[4,"Charmeleon"]]

let output = document.getElementById('output')
for (var key in arr) {
let button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerHTML = arr[key][1]
    button.addEventListener('click',go)
    button.setAttribute('data-key',arr[key][0])
    output.append(button)
}

data = []

fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json")
.then(response => {
   return response.json();
})

.then(jsondata => data.push(jsondata))

 
function go() {
  
  if (data.length > 0) {
    fetch()
    console.log('This data is new')
  }
  
  else {
        console.log('This data is not new')
  }
  
  
  let key = this.dataset.key
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src',data[0].pokemon[key].img)

}
```

```html
<img id="img" src=""/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Does anyone know how to load the data only when necessary?

Comment: First, the call to `fetch()` without a URL is invalid. Second, why trigger the fetch off a click? Why not just fetch immediately when the page loads, since presumably you're going to need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If needed some code optimization.

Add event listener to parent div instead of adding an event for each new button
This will reduce the number of event listeners.

```
output.addEventListener('click', go);
```

Use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead of updating DOM upon each new button creation.

```
let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
```

Append newly created button to fragment

```
  fragment.appendChild(button);
```

Finally, Append created fragment to target element `#output`

```
output.appendChild(fragment);
```

Then how to get dataset key of button in `go` function? Simple get target element on which click event was occurred then get its key using dataset.

```
let key = event.target.dataset.key;
```

Below code, if data length is 0. execution will wait for API call to finish, Hence [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). To use await we need to mark its container function as [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
let output = document.getElementById('output');

output.addEventListener('click', go);

let arr = [[0,"Bulbasaur"],[1,"Ivysaur"],[2,"Venusaur"],[3,"Charmander"],[4,"Charmeleon"]]
 
let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
for (var key in arr) {
  let button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerHTML = arr[key][1]
  //button.addEventListener('click',go)
  button.setAttribute('data-key',arr[key][0]);
  fragment.appendChild(button);
}
output.appendChild(fragment);

data = [];

async function go(event){
  if(data.length==0) {
    await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsondata => data.push(jsondata)); 
   }
   // get dataset of the target element
  let key = event.target.dataset.key;
  document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src',data[0].pokemon[key].img)
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src=""/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
let arr = [[0,"Bulbasaur"],[1,"Ivysaur"],[2,"Venusaur"],[3,"Charmander"],[4,"Charmeleon"]]
let output = document.querySelector('#output')
for (let key in arr) {
  let button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerHTML = arr[key][1]
  button.addEventListener('click',go)
  button.setAttribute('data-key',arr[key][0])
  output.append(button)
}
data = []
async function go() {
  if (data.length === 0) {
    await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(jsondata => data.push(jsondata))
    console.log('This data is new')
  }
  else {
    console.log('This data is not new')
  }
  let key = this.dataset.key
  document.querySelector('#img').setAttribute('src',data[0].pokemon[key].img)
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src=""/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had your conditional backwards so it did an empty fetch, seemed odd.
I set this up as an object and set the fetch inside one of the objects function and just called it - this also avoid pollution of the global namespace with a "common" variable name like "data" or "arr" etc.

```js
var myObject = {
  arr: [
    [0, "Bulbasaur"],
    [1, "Ivysaur"],
    [2, "Venusaur"],
    [3, "Charmander"],
    [4, "Charmeleon"]
  ],
  logMessage(message) {
    console.log(message);
  },
  go: function() {
    if (myObject.data.length <= 0) {
      myObject.goGetem()
      myObject.logMessage('This data is new');
    } else {
      myObject.logMessage('This data is not new');
    }
    let key = this.dataset.key;
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src', myObject.data[0].pokemon[key].img);
  },
  output: {},
  data: [],
  goGetem: function() {
    myObject.logMessage('retreiving data');
    fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(jsondata => myObject.data.push(jsondata))
      .then(function() {
        myObject.logMessage('We fetched data: ' + !!myObject.data.length);
        //use this to see what we got by uncommenting:
        //myObject.logMessage(myObject.data);
      });
  },
  setup: function() {
    myObject.output = document.getElementById('output');
    myObject.goGetem();
    for (var key in myObject.arr) {
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerHTML = myObject.arr[key][1];
      button.addEventListener('click', myObject.go);
      button.setAttribute('data-key', myObject.arr[key][0]);
      myObject.output.append(button);
    };
  }
};

myObject.setup();
```

```html
<img id="img" src="" />
<div id="output"></div>
```